# get form data from '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, form-data

I am passing uploaded file and dataObject in FormData:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("file", this.state.files);
data.append("data", formData);
```

`formData` is just a Json Object eg: formData = { "a":123 }

Passing data to the node server using `put` request with `axios` ,I am able to get the file object and data in req, but in data field it's giving `'[object Object]'`

Don't know how to access this. I tried JSON.parse(req.body.data), but getting error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: try using JSON.stringify(data) before sending it to the server

Comment: there's not enough context here, but it sounds like you've passed an actual JS object, which natively stringifies to that unhelpful `[object Object]`. You probably want to call `JSON.stringify` on it before you send it

Comment: what is `formData` object? You probably need to do `JSON.stringify(formData)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like `formData` is an object that's cast to string `[object Object]` prior to being sent on the wire. Try `data.append("data", JSON.stringify(formData))`.

Comment: Don't you mean `JSON.stringify(formData)` ? Or did I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Send the object with JSON.stringify and then use JSON.parse once you receive data, to make the  string object an object again.